# php mvc – Remove Public from URL

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, url, host

I know this is a very popular question but I haven't been able to find a working solution in my project 
I  want to set my document root to the public folder

**change url for example from /public/login to /login**

**.htaccess code**

```
  RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: > I don't want to set my document root to the public folder

Why not?

Comment: I wnat to set I edit it soory

Comment: Either use `php artisan serve` in your "project root" folder to serve files or set the `DocumentRoot` in your virtualhost to the `public` folder

Comment: i mixed laravel with php mvc i cant use artisan I want to change document root in cpanel or in .htaccess file

Answer (score 1):

I'd say this is the immediate answer to the question you asked:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?public/(.*)$ /%1 [QSA,R=301,END]
RewriteRule ^ /public%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,END]
```

But I assume this is more what you actually need, your question is vague in that:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?public/(.*)$ /%1 [QSA,R=301,END]
RewriteRule ^ /public/index.php?%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,END]
```

Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded and enabled into the http server and the interpretation of distributed configuration files (".htaccess") has to be granted in the http server's host configuration if you really want to use such.

It is a good idea to start out with a 302 temporary redirection and only change that to a 301 permanent redirection later, once you are certain everything is correctly set up. That prevents caching issues while trying things out...

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a distributed configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a distributed configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using distributed configuration files (".htaccess"). Those distributed configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes **.htacess** code doesnot work due to **mod_rewrite**. Try once using **mod_rewrite enable**. Alternately you can move you index.php file from public folder to main folder and update link that are used in **index.php** file. Another way is to use **php artisan serve** to run project and use htaccess that you have used.

Comment: Hi dear, i use mvc project and i can't move index.php to main folder
php artisan serv work to laravel, it doesn't work for me